# Highcharts - Removing title off tree maps

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am attempting to remove the labeling of my treemap. design Although I do want to reveal the name when hovering over the square of the tree-map; I am attempting to remove the titles of each square such as `In Store, Retail, Online, Street Vendors` etc..... But like mentioned earlier I do want to show the title when hovering over which is why I did not remove the names entirely;

I've tried accomplishing this goal by editing the `dataLabels` object; and setting `enabled: false`, I've also adjusted the styling of font and alignment in hopes to affect the text but that did not work either.

Here is a link to my highcharts [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/huzk2t5b/7/) example:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be accomplished by setting the dataLabels option on plotOptions. Like this:

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  series: [...],
  title: {
    text: 'Sector'
  },
  plotOptions: {
    series: {
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: false
      }
    }
  }
});
```

[Highcharts API](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.treemap.dataLabels.enabled)

Answer (score 1):

Notice that the `dataLabels` options object should be defined in the series options object, not the level one.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/hx4pjzg3/

```
series: [{
   dataLabels: {
     enabled: false
   }
}]
```

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.treemap.dataLabels